# PHP/PDO - use variable assignment as fetch-statement

Tags: php, variables, pdo

Okay - so I have a custom function

```
selectQuery($query, $fetch = 'fetch', $rowCount = 1, 
              $onlyRowCount = false, $outputerror = false)
```

Which works fine. However, I have one particular query where the `fetch`-method is `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0)`, and if I pass that as the `$fetch`-value in the function-call and try to use that in the output, it just returns `NULL`(because it doesn't work - the query works fine if run directly, or hard-coded).

So, what I'm asking, is there a way to use a value of a variable (which, at least to start with, is a string) to assign a fetch method?

I've tried the following:

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0); //works, but is hard-coded

$stmt->$fetch //returns NULL

$stmt->{$fetch} //returns NULL
```

So, is there a way to use that variable `$fetch` as the assignment directly? Casting the variable to something, or some other way?

Comment: This is not very clear. Please post the code for `selectQuery` and be sure your question contains a [mcve]. Right now, we'd be guessing about what's occurring inside your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is horrible. That long tail of parameters alone! And the lack of prepared statements. And a database related function that decides on its own whether to output an error or not, as though database interaction is something different from other code.

Do yourself a favor, make this function this way

```
function query($query, $parameters = []) {
    $pdo = // here your way of getting a PDO instance. 
    // DON't TELL ME YOU ARE CREATING A NEW ONE EVERY TIME
    if (!$parameters)
    {
         return $this->query($sql);
    }
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    return $stmt;
}
```

This is ALL you need and it's MUCH better than you have at the moment.

Returning a statement is the key. It lets you to attach any fetch method you like to the function call - the most natural way of getting different result types from such a function. Or not to fetch anything at all, if a query happens to be UPDATE or INSERT.

Want a row count?

```
$count = query("DELETE FROM usars")->rowCount();
```

want a fetch?

```
$user = query("select * from users where id=?", [$id])->fetch();
```

want fetchAll with PDO::FETCH_COLUMN? here you are

```
$users = query("select name from users")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Simple, usable, flexible, readable and **secure**.

If you don't know how to make this function connect only once, here is a link to a simple [PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper) I wrote. **Note the examples section.** It is so exciting that I'd better put it here:

```
# Table creation
DB::query("CREATE temporary TABLE pdowrapper 
           (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(255))");

# Prepared statement multiple execution
$stmt = DB::prepare("INSERT INTO pdowrapper VALUES (NULL, ?)");
foreach (['Sam','Bob','Joe'] as $name)
{
    $stmt->execute([$name]);
}
$id = DB::lastInsertId());

# Getting rows in a loop
$stmt = DB::run("SELECT * FROM pdowrapper");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['name'], PHP_EOL;
}

# Getting one row
$id  = 1;
$row = DB::run("SELECT * FROM pdowrapper WHERE id=?", [$id])->fetch();

# Getting single field value
$name = DB::run("SELECT name FROM pdowrapper WHERE id=?", [$id])->fetchColumn();

# Getting array of rows
$all = DB::run("SELECT name, id FROM pdowrapper")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

# Update
$new = 'Sue';
$count = DB::run("UPDATE pdowrapper SET name=? WHERE id=?", [$new, $id])->rowCount();
```

Comment: I prefer having a function that handles all the different functions, so I don't have to run multiple queries to get things like row count. And the only thing I need to use is the query to run the function. All the others have defaults. And of course it is not running a prepared statement, it's using PDO `query()`, not `prepare()`.

Comment: Uhm... No, there is no point in using prepare instead of query when you have absolutely no variables to prepare. Which this function is for. But I see your point for the other items, and I might be able to simplify.

Comment: I believe that you said you need a "function that handles all the different functions" - so this function does, handling SELECT queries with prepared statements, SELECT queries without prepared statements, as well as UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries with or without prepared statements. Not to mention SET, SHOW, CREATE and ALTER queries. So it is literally fulfills your needs. But of course you can add a condition to avoid a prepare when it is not needed. If is implemented in the wrapper I linked in my question.

Comment: I'll have a look. The linked content looked a bit better,and might be a solution for what I need to do. I wish it was possible to do method chaining...

Comment: The method cnaining is always possible. Why do you think it is not? The method chaining makes your code more flexible, more readable (you can always tell what does it do without consulting a documentation like with your own function, it makes your PHP editor to hint you available methods

Comment: No, it's not. At least I can't see it being possible? I'm on my phone, so reading code isn't that easy, what I mean is something like `$stmt = DB::run(query)->fetchAll()->rowCount()` and similar. Is that possible with the code in the link? And then getting both the data from the query and the row count, easily accessible in the same result-array/variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a variable function call. But the problem here is that you pass the function name `fetchAll` with its parameters `(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0)` as one argument to your `selectQuery` function.

I think you need to pass the target function name as one argument, and the target function parameters as another argument.

```
selectQuery($query, $fetch = 'fetch', $rowCount = 1, 
              $onlyRowCount = false, $outputerror = false, $params= array())

{...
    call_user_func_array($stmt->$fetch, $params);
...}
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: JFYI, your code doesn't follow the example from the link you posted

Comment: @YourCommonSense  you mean the part of passing `$stmt->fetch` to the `call_user_func_array`  ?

Answer (score 0):

After rewieving the answer by [@Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense), I ended up with this function inside my DB-class:

```
    public static function Query($query, $prepared = [], $outputerror = true) {
        /* Lets a user run a query directly via $core->Query()
        /* First variable is the actual query
        /* Second variable is the variables array (for prepared queries) [':var1'=>$var1],[$var1,$var2] and so on
        /* Third variable tells whether or not to output errormessages - default no (false)
        /* Use the function like $row = $core->Query(); Minimum you need to enter $query */
        $dbprefix = Config::read('dbprefix');
        $core = Core::getInstance();
        $stmt = '';
        if (!empty($query)) {
            if (!$prepared) {
                $stmt = $core->dbh->query($query);
                if ($stmt !== false) {
                    return $stmt;   
                } elseif ($outputerror === true) {
                    echo displayErrors($stmt, true, __FILE__);
                }
            } else {
                $stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($query);
                if ($stmt !== false) {
                    $stmt->execute($prepared);
                } elseif ($outputerror === true) {
                    echo displayErrors($stmt, true, __FILE__);
                }
            }
            return $stmt;
        }
    } // end function Query
```

Works perfectly, involves a bit of a rewrite in my other files, but that was expected

I've rewarded the answer to [@Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the function uses a specific logging mechanism, which limits what is output to the user, regardless of PHPs error-settings. The errors get logged regardless, of course. It is just an easier solution while in development. It will normally be set to false, I just needed it to be set to true while changing over. I know I can set the exception type in attributes, but given that this needs to be possible to control by the user, it's easier this way, since I can't get a setting from the database before the connection to the database is actually made.

Comment: That's strange an attitude. There are thousands kinds of errors - filesystem, permission, syntax, logic, runtime and other - all handled exactly the same way. But for some reason you are obsessed with just a single kind of error. And on top of that you have to change over every time it goes from dev to prod by hand in the every function call. I will never understand that. There is nothing to show to the user actually. "Mysql server has gone away" will tell him literally nothing. Not a mature site is showing anything like that. Have you ever seen such a "limited" error shown on SO? FB? Reddit?

Comment: Database errors can contain information that does not need to be publicly available, hence I prefer controlling them separately. It will be changed to an internal call to a config-setting when moved to production (ie, no longer a function call). The system already writes logs to a separate log in the actual installation folder, so as to give users without access to the filesystem (shared hosts, fx) access to the logs, but again, returning an error saying a file could not be loaded, for instance, is not that big a deal. Returning the login info for the database is slightly worse..

Comment: Just asking, are you aware of the set_error_handler() function which controls how the error message have to be processed from a single place, once for all errors, regardless of origin?

Answer (score -1):

This works in my test to run a different fetch method per the argument:

```
function query($sql, $fetch) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', 'xxxx');
    $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
    $result = $stmt->$fetch();
    return $result;
}
```

(I'm not suggesting making a new connection for every query, that's just what I did for my test.)

However, trying to make a dynamic call to control the fetch mode and other arguments would be more complex. I'd suggest creating a callable:

```
function query($sql, $fetch, $setFetchModeArgs = null) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', 'masterkey');
    $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
    if ($setFetchModeArgs != null) {
        call_user_func_array([$stmt, "setFetchMode"], $setFetchModeArgs);
    }
    $result = $stmt->$fetch();
    return $result;
}

query("SELECT ...", "fetchAll", [PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0]);
```

Anyway, that's how to make what you're trying to do work. But I don't think this is a good design.